# Have two radio buttons (yes or no), with values of 0 or 1 to input to database. How to echo user choice with 'yes' or 'no'?

Tags: php, mysql, radio-button, echo

I have two radio buttons.

```
<input name='option' id='newsletter' type='radio' value=1>Yes 

<input name='option' id='newsletter' type='radio' value=0>No
```

When the user presses submit it takes them to a page which shows their choice.

```
echo "<p>Your newsletter preference $_POST[option]</p>";
```

This will display their choice as a 1 or 0. How can I get it to display 'yes' or 'no'?
Note: Values can't be changed

Comment: Yes, that would be the obvious thing to do. Unfortunately it's for a study exercise, and the rules say that's how it must be.

Comment: Yeah looks like I'll do it through an if statement. Just asked the question, in case there was an even simpler way to do it.

Comment: `echo "<p>Your newsletter preference ". (($_POST[option] == 1)?"Yes":"No") . "</p>";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`identical operator` means triple equal sign.

```
$selection=$_POST["option"];

        if ($selection ==1) {
          echo "Yes";
        } else {
        echo "No";
        }
```

Comment: This is correct. 
However I'm always getting a 'No' echoed when using the triple equal sign...
It's working with == though.

Answer (score 0):

Use if condition

```
        $selection=$_POST["option"];

        if ($selection == 1) {
          echo "Yes";
        } else {
        echo "No";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$selected_radio=$_POST[option]
if($selected_radio==1){
  echo "<p>Your newsletter preference is Yes</p>";
}
else if($selected_radio==0){
  echo "<p>Your newsletter preference is No</p>";
}
```

Thanks.